# How to break a <tr> on several lines without changing the HTML layout?

Tags: css

I've looked at all the questions related to this issue, but none is answered as I wish. I have a table where the last column holds a lot of details. I want this last column to be in its own line:

```
| Last Name | First Name | Email          |
===========================================
| Doe       | John       | john@doe.com   |
-------------------------------------------
| Some long information about John        |
===========================================
| Smith     | Jane       | jane@smith.com |
-------------------------------------------
| Some long information about Jane        |
===========================================
```

I've tried various `display` setups, but there is always something wrong. When the layout is correct (for example, when the `tr` is `flex`) the headers and the content are not aligned.

I also don't want a solution based on magic `px` values. All my CSS uses `[r]em` and I want to keep this.

```css
tr, tr td, tr th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  display: inline;
}

td:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th style="display:none">Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>john@doe.com</td>
    <td>Some long information about John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>jane@smith.com</td>
    <td>Some long information about Jane</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I must keep the HTML layout as is: I cannot add a `tr` for the last column, but I can add classes.

I do not need a generic solution: the number of columns is fixed, and I can rely on this.

Is it even possible to achieve this?

Comment: do a research on `thead` and `tbody` tags, and also `colspan` attribute to the `td`, it probably will do what you want

Comment: Can you not use colspan?

Comment: @Laif What do you mean?

Comment: `<td colspan="3">` makes a table cell span 3 columns, for instance

Comment: @Laif I know, but how does it solve my issue?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Is [this](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/KKwoRrR) what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Laif Nope, I specifically said that I don't want to change the HTML. There is a JS script that relies to the fact that every line is a user information.

Comment: To answer your question then, you can't do that. Use CSS grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205697/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-laif).

Comment: Can't use on my current network unfortunately, good luck

Comment: You can't change anything in HTML? Not even adding a class? If you cant, then sorry, but it is impossible, unless you know that every row will have 4 columns, then *maybe* a solution can be found

Comment: @CalvinNunes I can add a class! I mean that I cannot add/remove a tag. I've clarified this in my question.

Comment: Dont believe it is possible to change dom structures with css. Would the use of jquery be an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @TravisActon I am only allowed to use vanilla JS in this project, but I guess that the JQuery can be translated to some JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you want is something that is a little weird, because you want to change the way a table works, since a cell (`td`) should be in column like the other cells and not filling an entire row just for itself, that's why it's hard to do it.

But add a class to the column that has the "big information", then you can add some CSS to force this cell to break down and become like a row, by using some `flex` attributes.

Take a look if the below code is useful for you, and note some changes I made in CSS:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1;
}

th {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px;
}

tr > .cellAsRow {
  width: 100%;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th style="display:none">Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>john@doe.com</td>
    <td class="cellAsRow">Some long information about John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>jane@smith.com</td>
    <td class="cellAsRow">Some long information about Jane</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Be aware that with this CSS "forcing" a `td` down it will be really hard to control the cells sizes and the table layout

Comment: IIUC, it works because each column has a forced identical size, doesn't it?

Comment: not exactly, there 's nothing explicitly forcing width there, but the `flex` properties have his own way of setting sizes, you can still set a `max-width` for the first cells, for example: `tr > *:nth-child(1) {
  max-width: 20%
}` this will make the column "Last Name" to use a maximun of 20% of table width

Comment: BTW, `tr > .cellAsRow` can become `td:last-child` so there's no need for a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution that will maintain automatic sizing of column widths. However, it only works with a specific height of rows. The row with most of the data and the row with "big information" can be different heights, but they must be the same height for each entry.

```css
tr td, tr th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

table {
  /* add spacing between rows to make room for the extra row */
  /* add 2px to spacing and padding to account for border */
  border-spacing: 0px calc(1rem + 2px);
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

tr {
  /* transforming tr allows absolute positioning of child elements */
  transform: scale(1);
}

tr td:last-child {
  /* manually wrap the last column */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* border is calculated differently when absolutely positioned, this fixes it */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* this only works with one line of text, so hide excess */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th style="display:none">Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='one'>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>john@doe.com</td>
    <td>Some long information about John and just a little extra to show the ellipses</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>jane@smith.com</td>
    <td>Some long information about Jane</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```